# How do you push HTML into an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, jquery-ui

1. I have an array which is currently pulling through the Title of an item
2. This array is then used as the source of jQuery UI's autocomplete.
3. When typing into a HTML input, the autocomplete finds the list of Titles from the array
4. I would like to us the ID of the item to append to the URL when clicking search (Its currently configured to push the Title as that's what's in the Array

When pushing the ID into the array, naturally both the Title and ID are being displayed in the autocomplete drop down. However, I do not want the ID to be displayed, I simply what to extract it, based on the title so I can append it to the url.

The difficulty i'm currently having is that if I try to create a HTML structure as a variable to push into an array, the HTML is display within the HTML input box when typing.

For example:

```
var prodResultTite = $(this).attr('ows_Title');
                        var prodResultID = $(this).attr('ows_ID');
                        var prodResultContainer = '<div class="result" id="' + prodID + '">' + prodTitle + '</div>';

                        //itemTitle.push($(this).attr('ows_Title'));
                        itemTitle.push(prodResultContainer);
```

This results in the input field displaying:

```
'<div class="result" id="' + 125+ '">' + My Product Title + '</div>';
```

As you can see, the ID and Title are pulled through perfectly, however, the HTML is also dragged through.

Is there anyway for the HTML to literally be a div rather than a string in this instance?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code but just one point you should pay attention to.

in autoComplete you should have a `<a></a>` tag for each suggestion or you will not be able to hover on items or select an item. because it triggered by clicking in the `<a></a>` tag.

HTML

```
<input id="search" type="text"/>

<div id="itemcontainer" style="display:none">
  <div class="item" id="id_1" title="Item 1">Item1</div>
  <div class="item" id="id_2" title="Item 2">Item2</div>
  <div class="item" id="id_3" title="Item 3">Item3</div>
  <div class="item" id="id_4" title="Item 4">Item4</div>
</div>

<input type="button" id="seeVal" value=" see autocompele html" />
```

CSS

```
.result , .result *{
  color:#f00 !important;
}
.result#id_2 ,.result#id_2 *{
  color:#00f !important;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  /*var items = [
  {
    id:1,label:'lbl1'
  },
  {
    id:2,label:'lbl2'
  },
  {
    id:4,label:'the label3'
  },
  {
    id:5,label:'the label4'
  },
];*/

var items=[];

$('#itemcontainer').find('.item').each(function(){
  items[items.length]={'id':$(this).attr('id'),'label':$(this).html()}
});

$('#search').autocomplete({  
  minLength: 0,
  source:items,
  focus: function( event, ui ) {
    $('#search').val( ui.item.label );
    return false;
  },
  select: function( event, ui ) {
    $('#search').val( ui.item.label );

    return false;
  }
}).data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = (function( ul, item ) {
  var $div=$('<div></div>').addClass('result').attr('id',item.id).html('<a>'+item.label+'</a>');
return $( "<li>" )
.append($div)
.appendTo(ul);
});

  $('#seeVal').on('click',function(){
    alert($('.result').parent().parent().html());
  });
});
```

Here is updated codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sjmeB

the 'seeVal' button and CSS are for testing the output

Comment: Thanks very much for the rapid response. I just tried that approach and unfortunately the array (autocomplete dropdown) isn't populated and cannot find the title values. (I randomly tried something very similar previously)

Comment: sorry my internet connection failed. I don't understand what you mean? As I know you can use a JSON datasource for autocomplete. And also a php file which takes an input (value of the text) and generates that JSON. Please explain more what you mean? (my English id not so good).

Comment: No problem at all, I appreciate the help :). Previously the array built by the "Title" variable worked perfectly fine. However, I'm trying to push a div container with the ID and Title inside to the array. When doing this (your example) the dropdown from jQuery UI's autocomplete doesn't display any values to select from. I hope that helps.

Comment: Oh so you are trying to create a custom dropdown which shows a div instead of a simple text right?

Comment: Almost. The jQueryUI AutoComplete displays the drop down. The source of the data in the drop down is the title that I pushed into the array. However, I would like the title and the id to be pushed into the array inside a div so I can reference attributes etc. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I can't understand what you mean than `I would like the title and the id to be pushed into the array inside a div so I can reference attributes`. I think you should keep data in JSON and second check these to check that you meant this http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data or not. ( press view source). and also give me a link to page you are working on and tell me what you are trying to do to help me get the main idea.

Comment: Thanks Imsiso. Unfortunately I'm working inside a Microsoft content management system for a confidential client which I cannot link to. The information that's being pushed into an array is from a list inside the content management system. In short, the best way I can summarise it is if you use jQuery UI's autocomplete in CodePen (for example) and populate the source of the autocomplete with a HTML div that contains data. I appreciate your time so far. :)

Comment: ok I will try, and I will upload a example in my host. but please give me an example of outputed array and also what is the code you wrote in your question? I mean where is it? insode a loop or what?

Comment: I imsiso, I quickly jotted this up: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vBnCu - This is the jquery autocomplete. Instead of the array being "item 1"  & "item 2" etc, I would like it to be '<div class="result">' + item + '</div>'. I want that to appear in the dropdown in the exact same way it currently does, but to have a div hidden around it

Comment: you I think got it.You want to have no change in look but just you want that div in background right? for what do you want to put that div in a place(ie another div)(when one item is selected or hovered?) or its just a way to keep an Id and maybe some extra data for a title to use it again?

Comment: Yes, almost. Basically, I want the look, feel and behavior in my example (Which i have just updated) to be exactly the same. However, in my example you can see that the arrayData is using the item "title" for the autocomplete. I would like to have the "Title" and "ID" within a div container. I have added a comment in the js of what i would like to be pushed into the array.

Comment: please check this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bzovphttp://codepen.io/anon/pen/bzovp

Comment: wait I forgot to save it. and I had wrote that before your update so wait.

Comment: Hi Imsiso - Unfortunately not. I have updated mine here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vBnCu - This shows what I'm trying to push into the array. If you look in the input box, the html appears. Whereas, I would simply like the title to appear, but really, the title is inside a div container called "results" inside the input. Again, very much appreciate you taking the time to try and understand this, thank you :)

Comment: Your welcome. When I start a work I should finish it. Oh I now understand you want to change the structure behind the autocomplete so you would be able to assign an Id for each items of suggestion. But I'm now busy please give me sometime cause I now how to do it.

Comment: oh sorry for being late I was busy and also my internet connection was too slow. check this it should be what you were looking for.please let me know if it was. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sjmeB

Comment: No need to apologise. That works fantastically. Thank you so much for your continued time and effort on this. It's greatly appreciated. :) - Are you able to update your answer and I'll mark it as correct? Again, thank you :)